# Css child selector :first-child, but select all children in targeted selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, superfish

Not sure if the title is a little vague or not,

However, lets say you have..

```css
.topactive a:focus, .topactive a:hover, 
.sf-menu a:active:first-child, .sf-menu li.sfHover:first-child {
}
```

and in your html your looking at:

all the ul and li class declarations;

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li class="current">
<p class="topactive"><a href="#a">About Us</a></p>
        <ul class="menu2"><li>submenu</li></ul></li>
    <li>something</li>
        <ul><li>submenu</li></ul>
</ul>
```

I need it to target the left most li only.

Is the css selecting only "example", as in my current code it is, and i cannot select only the first level ul explicitly, its only selecting the first instance of ul.

I hope this makes sense, sorry for any ambiguity and thanks to those who helped on my other question.

Comment: I read it three times but couldn't get what you want or facing.

Comment: Oops sorry! I need the css to target the first level of li if that makes sense? Nothing beyond ul li, but every first level li. I have updated my op.

Comment: I was going to comment on the accepted answer to your other question talking about how `:first-child` isn't enough to select just the top-level element.

Comment: I apologise for the wording and phrasing of my question, however I have found a method to fix this below and will accepted when the timer allows me. Thanks for the perseverance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select only the first-level children of the top-most `ul` you need some way to explicitly reference the ancestor and the distance from said ancestor. I'd suggest using an `id`:

```
#idOfTopMostUL > li {
    /* CSS for the first-level li-elements */
}
#idOfTopMostUL ul li {
    /* CSS for other li elements, that are children of ul elements within the ul */
}
```

Which would require HTML such as:

```
<ul id="idOfTopMostUL">
    <li>example
        <ul><li>submenu</li></ul></li>
    <li>something
        <ul><li>submenu</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQSb/).

Please note that I've corrected your HTML (a `ul` cannot be a direct child of another `ul` (or `ol`)).

If you don't want to, or can't, give your `ul` an `id` you can reference another ancestor outside of the `ul` (since the first-level `li` elements will be closer to that ancestor than the nested-`li`s):

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <ul>
        <li>example
            <ul><li>submenu</li></ul></li>
        <li>something
            <ul><li>submenu</li></ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#parentDiv > ul > li {
    /* CSS for the first-level li-elements */
}
#parentDiv ul ul li,
#parentDiv ul li ul li {
    /* CSS for other li elements, that are children of ul elements within the ul */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQSb/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this when I can, this method using the > works well thanks :-) sorry for my very bad worded question!

Comment: Don't worry too much about it, though obviously the more clearly you can express your question/problem the easier it is for us to help you. And you're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

The specific CSS you'er showing isn't selecting anything in the HTML you've shown us.  The first two rules both require `.topactive` and that isn't present in your HTML.  The next two rules both require `.sf-menu` and that isn't present in your HTML either.

If you want only the first level of children on an object, use the direct child designator `>` in your rules.

In the HTML you've actually shown us, you can select all first level li elements of your top level ul with this CSS:

```
body > ul > li
```

But, in the real world, you would probably designate your top level ul objects with a class or id and do something like this:

```
#myTop > li
```

or

```
.myTop > li
```

Where you put the `myTop` class or id on the top level `UL` elements.

Comment: This selector isn't enough because every `li` is a child of a `ul`; you'll have to anchor the `ul` selector to some other parent that isn't shown in the markup.